# Unique Identifier of Every Drupal User Instance

Tags: 7, forms

I've been developing a custom module in my drupal system. One user account can be simultaneously access in different computer/browser. For example:

```
Username: ghlatorre
Computers accessing my system/module using the username ghlatorre: Computers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Is there a unique identifier I could use to differentiate these different system user instances?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *uniquely identify browsers*, Drupal tracks browser sessions via the `sid` & `ssid` column in its `sessions` table.

If you're looking to *uniquely identify computers*, you could try the [IP address manager module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip).

> IP address manager records user IP addresses, and allows admins to
>   view which IP addresses have been tracked against a user, and which
>   users have been known to use a certain IP address. This can be
>   currently used to identify duplicate accounts.
>
> The aim of this module is to provide a way to identify a user when
>   they are not logged in to provide some action or context to their
>   presence by maintaining lists of users for some purpose - such as, but
>   not limited to, banning them.

The caveats with this approach is, depending on the network setup between the client & host, you might get false duplicate IP addresses for users (e.g. a home network router using NAT).

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Manifest user lists](https://www.drupal.org/project/manifest) module.

**MANIFEST USER LISTS:**

- Creates lists of users for some arbitrary purpose (usually administrative).
- Modules can add options to a manifest list, in order to act on users in that manifest.
- Users can be added to a list via their user role, through the profile page, actions, Views Bulk Operations, or through user update operations.

> This module was originally created to provide the common functionality between [Cave your trolls](https://www.drupal.org/project/cave) and [Misery](https://www.drupal.org/project/misery), as well as eventually identifying anonymous users as known users through [IP address manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip) and possibly other methods.